# How to Deploy App on iPad using Monotouch Professional Licence

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I purchased MonoTouch Professional but while debugging with the iPhone it gives an error: “No 
Valid iPhone code signing keys found in keychain”.

The store page of Xamarin https://store.xamarin.com/ for the Professional version shows two important things however:

- Deploy to your devices
- Publish to app stores

I connected my device but I don’t know how to actually get my app running on the iPhone. Basically I have two questions:

- How to configure the iPhone to debug with?
- How to deploy app to the iPhone with MonoTouch (Professional License) version?

A third, seperate question is if it is necessary to enroll in the iOS Developer program from
Apple. If so, which is suitable for us because I don’t want to put my app on to the App 
Store.

My app is only available to our clients for their internal use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enroll you to the iOS Developer Programm otherwise you cant deploy to devices. If you dont like to Publish to the App Store you also can deploy Apps with the TestFlight SDK. It´s a free SDK which allows you to Deploy Apps without the App Store.

Comment: it's important to note that TestFlight helps automate and manage AdHoc deployments - it still requires you to be a paid member of the Apple iOS Dev Program.

Comment: You forgot to mention that you can be an enterprise developer which does not deploy to the App store but publishes ad-hoc builds.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, you should start from their iPhone tutorial,

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/getting_started/Hello_iPhone#Deploying_to_the_Device

where deploying to device is mentioned. Also you need to learn from Apple resources, such as

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/Xcode-4-Deploying-Your-App-to-Your-Own-iPhone-iPad-iPod-touch.aspx

Comment: Further, there are some really good tutorials on distribution, including ad-hoc distribution on the Xamarin site:

- http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/building_for_distribution
- http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/IPA_Support_-_Ad_Hoc_and_Enterprise_Deployment
- http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Publishing_to_the_App_Store

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is the tutorial you need to follow. There are lots of hidden buttons you wown't find by yourself

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/device_provisioning/